# Swift - How to load videos from photo album and display them in collection view

Tags: ios, swift, video, uicollectionview

I used `PHImageManager` to load images from photo album.
Here is my code...

```
var photoLibrary = [UIImage]()
    func grabPhotos(){
        let imgManager = PHImageManager.default()

        let requestOptions = PHImageRequestOptions()
        requestOptions.isSynchronous = true
        requestOptions.deliveryMode = .highQualityFormat

        let fetchOptions = PHFetchOptions()
        fetchOptions.sortDescriptors = [NSSortDescriptor(key: "creationDate", ascending: false)]
        if let fetchResult : PHFetchResult = PHAsset.fetchAssets(with: .image, options: fetchOptions) {
            if fetchResult.count > 0 {
                for i in 0..<fetchResult.count{
                    imgManager.requestImage(for: fetchResult.object(at: i) as PHAsset , targetSize: CGSize(width: 200, height: 200), contentMode: .aspectFill, options: requestOptions, resultHandler: {
                        image, error in
                        self.photoLibrary.append(image!)
                    })
                }
            }
            else{
                showAllertToImportImage()//A function to show alert
            }
        }
    }
```

Now I want to load videos from photo album and I need to show them in `UICollectionView`.
For loading images in `UICollectionView` I used `UIImageView` in the cell. What should I use in the cell to load videos ?
I also need to show the video duration.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please see answer of fetch video and duration of video

```
  func grabPhotos(){
    let imgManager = PHImageManager.default()

    let requestOptions = PHImageRequestOptions()
    requestOptions.isSynchronous = true
    requestOptions.deliveryMode = .highQualityFormat

    let fetchOptions = PHFetchOptions()
    fetchOptions.sortDescriptors = [NSSortDescriptor(key: "creationDate", ascending: false)]
    if let fetchResult : PHFetchResult = PHAsset.fetchAssets(with: .video, options: fetchOptions) {
        if fetchResult.count > 0 {
                for i in 0..<fetchResult.count{

 //Used for fetch Image//
imgManager.requestImage(for: fetchResult.object(at: i) as PHAsset , targetSize: CGSize(width: 200, height: 200), contentMode: .aspectFill, options: requestOptions, resultHandler: {
                    image, error in
                    let imageOfVideo = image! as UIImage
                    self.photoLibrary.append(imageOfVideo)
                })
  //Used for fetch Video//
 imgManager.requestAVAsset(forVideo: fetchResult.object(at: i) as PHAsset, options: PHVideoRequestOptions(), resultHandler: {(avAsset, audioMix, info) -> Void in
                    if let asset = avAsset as? AVURLAsset {
                        //let videoData = NSData(contentsOf: asset.url)
                        let duration : CMTime = asset.duration
                       let durationInSecond = CMTimeGetSeconds(duration)
                        print(durationInSecond)
                    }



                })
            }

        }
        else{
            //showAllertToImportImage()//A function to show alert
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I used UIImageVIew in the cell of UICollectionView to show images. What should I use for videos ?? Any idea?? @Amit Verma

Comment: This  will provide you image and you can also make image by video Data like Thumbimage,         imgManager.requestImage(for: fetchResult.object(at: i) as PHAsset , targetSize: CGSize(width: 200, height: 200), contentMode: .aspectFill, options: requestOptions, resultHandler: {
                    image, error in
                    self.photoLibrary.append(image!)
                })

Comment: you used **self.photoLibrary.append(imageOfVideo)** for fetching images. Like this i used **self.videoDurationArray.append(String(durationInSecond))**  and added this lines **let labelView = cell.viewWithTag(2) as! UILabel** **labelView.text = videoDurationArray[indexPath.row]** in **func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {...}** ... NSLog says index out of range :(